# Error: Caused by: com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class java.util.LinkedHashMap not found nor either of his superclass in this context

Tags: java, json, xml, formatting, dtd

I want to convert a XML to a JSON and after some process returning to a valid XML with the DTD schema.

I have this method that returns a JSONObject:

```
public JSONObject xml2JSON(InputStream xml) throws IOException, JDOMException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = xml.read(buffer)) > -1 ) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        baos.flush();
        InputStream is1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        InputStream is2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        String s = input2String(is1);
        if(validationDTD(is2)) {
            return XML.toJSONObject(s);
        }
        return null;
    }

public Boolean validationDTD(InputStream xml) throws JDOMException, IOException {
    try {
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder(XMLReaders.DTDVALIDATING);
        Document validDocument = builder.build(xml);
        validDocument.getDocType();
        return true;
    } catch (JDOMException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
public String input2String(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    return IOUtils.toString(inputStream, Charset.defaultCharset());
}
```

And this method that returns the proper xml:

```
public String JSONtoXML(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    String finalString = DOCTYPE.concat(XML.toString(jsonObject));
    return finalString;
}
```

with a variable for adding the DTD:

```
private static final String DOCTYPE = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
        "<!DOCTYPE ep-request SYSTEM \"myDtd.dtd\">";
```

I have this tests:

```
@Test
public void xml2JSONShouldReturnString() throws IOException, JDOMException {
    InputStream xmlInputString = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myXmlDtd.xml");
    service.xml2JSON(xmlInputString);
}

@Test
public void validateDTDShouldReturnDocument() throws IOException, JDOMException {
    InputStream xmlInputString = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myXmlDtd.xml");
    Assert.assertEquals(true, service.validationDTD(xmlInputString));
}

@Test
public void JSON2toxmlShouldReturnValidXML() throws IOException, JDOMException {
    InputStream xmlInputString = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myXmlDtd.xml");
    JSONObject jsonObject = service.xml2JSON(xmlInputString);
    String xmlOut = eblService.JSONtoXML(jsonObject);
    Assert.assertEquals(true, service.validationDTD(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlOut.getBytes())));
}
```

But the last one fails because the xml isn´t in the correct format of my DTD.

How can I make a valid XML (that matches the DTD)?

EDIT:
Now I'm parsing the XML to POJO (generated with xjc -dtd mydtd.dtd) and POJO to JSON, and viceversa.
But I'm having troubles with POJO to XML serialization because My POJO contains:

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "file-reference-id", required = true, type = 
FileReferenceId.class),
     @XmlElement(name = "request-petition", required = true, type = 
    RequestPetition.class)
    })
protected List<Object> fileRefenceIdOrRequestPetition;
```

the problem appears when my POJO contains a List of LinkedHashMap and returns that LinkedHashMap isn't in the JAXBContext, but if I change the type of my class to LinkedHashMap.class it misses the context of my FileReferenceId.class or whatever class that it its contained into the linkedHashMap.class

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, the most important part and I forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different libraries for converting JSON to XML and they all produce different answers, with different strengths and weaknesses. (For example, they all have different solutions to the problem of handling JSON keys that aren't valid XML names.) Generally they don't give you much control over the format of the XML, which means that you typically have to transform the generated XML to the format you actually want, e.g. with an XSLT stylesheet. That will certainly be the case if you have a specific DTD that the XML has to conform to.

Note: The `json-to-xml()` function in XSLT 3.0 produces XML that directly reflects the JSON grammar, with constructs like

```
<map>
  <string key="first">John</string>
  <string key="last">Smith</string>
</map>
```

The idea here is that users will *always* want to transform this into their desired target format, and since you're in XSLT already, this transformation poses no problems.

Comment: Hi, now I'm using the Jackson for POJO JSON conversions and JAXB for XML POJO conversions, I have a problem marshalling the POJO into the XML string.

Comment: If you have a problem, StackOverflow is the place to raise it. But not in a comment on an answer to a previous problem.